# angular ngShow animation not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-show

this is from angularjs example

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

I put everything in my local

why is not working on my local ?

what did I miss ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app="animateApp">
  <head>
```

SKIPPED THE STYLE PART.. SINCE IT'S TOO LONG

```
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script>
      angular.module('animateApp', ['ngAnimate']);
      var thumbsUp = element(by.css('span.glyphicon-thumbs-up'));
      var thumbsDown = element(by.css('span.glyphicon-thumbs-down'));

      it('should check ng-show / ng-hide', function() {
          expect(thumbsUp.isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy();
          expect(thumbsDown.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();

          element(by.model('checked')).click();

          expect(thumbsUp.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
          expect(thumbsDown.isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy();
      });

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Animation - Animate</h2>

Click me: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"><br/>
<div>
    Show:
    <div class="check-element animate-show" ng-show="checked">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> I show up when your checkbox is checked.
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    Hide:
    <div class="check-element animate-show" ng-hide="checked">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span> I hide when your checkbox is checked.
    </div>
</div>
```

```
          .animate-show {
          line-height:20px;
          opacity:1;
          padding:10px;
          border:1px solid black;
          background:white;
      }

      .animate-show.ng-hide-add,
      .animate-show.ng-hide-remove {
          display:block!important;
      }

      .animate-show.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
      .animate-show.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
          -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
          transition:all linear 0.5s;
      }

      .animate-show.ng-hide {
          line-height:0;
          opacity:0;
          padding:0 10px;
      }

      .check-element {
          padding:10px;
          border:1px solid black;
          background:white;
      }
```

Comment: Is your `angular-animate.js` really in a different directory than your `angular.min.js`? That looks fishy.

Comment: now I got  "element is not defined " error ..

Comment: style part is the part which will control how it animate. So you need to include that part here. If its too long, then get it shorter and post it here. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations

Comment: Can you provide your controller as well

Comment: also, add what you expect to happen and what IS actually not working for you.

Comment: Are you expecting animation?

Answer (score 3):

From what I can gather from the code you provided; this is what you were looking for...

[working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CriddleCraddle/1464j23a/)

**Note:** I changed some CSS to get the fade out working.  I also don't really know what is not working for you. Your question mentions ng-show animation, but I don't see any code trying to animate on show.  When I put your code in a jsFiddle, the checkbox did not work, as well as there was no animation on ng-hide.  Both are working in the jsFiddle now.  Is that what you were looking for? If not, let's work it out.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {});
```

HTML...

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <body>
      <h2>Animation - Animate</h2>
      Click me:
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked">
      <br/>
      <div>Show:
        <div class="check-element animate-show" ng-show="checked">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
            I show up when your checkbox is checked.</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          Hide:
          <div class="check-element animate-show" ng-hide="checked">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
            I hide when your checkbox is checked.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS...

```
.animate-show {
  line-height:20px;
  opacity:1;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:white;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide-add, .animate-show.ng-hide-remove {
  display:block!important;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide-add {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide {
  line-height:0;
  opacity:0;
  padding:0 10px;
}

.check-element {
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:white;
}
```